# Error in storing the result from mysql in a php variable pdo

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I'm using the code for getting the result of the mysql query using pdo into php variable 
But I'm facing some issues and not able to store the result of the query into the Variable
The Error MEssage
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in ... line 4

```
<?php
require 'test.php';
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vup_file";
    if ($STH = $DBH->query($sql)) {
    # check the row count
    if ($STH->fetchColumn() > 0) {

   echo $STH;
    }
    else {
        echo "No rows matched the query.";
    }
}

?>
```

---

For clarification, from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135425/error-in-storing-the-result-from-mysql-in-a-php-variable-pdo/26135545?noredirect=1#comment40965185_26135545)...

> I want to store the Maximum Id value in a php variable using pdo

Comment: `$DBH` should be declared as global

Comment: just make sure that `$DBH` is an instance of pdo connection, is the connection inside `test.php`?

Comment: `$DBH= new PDO('mssql:host=sqlserver;dbname=database', 'username',
'password');`

Comment: I changed according to the test.php my connection file but I m getting the error Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in

Comment: What did you expect to get from `echo $STH`? `$STH` is an instance of `PDOStatement` which cannot be implicitly converted to a string

Comment: @u_mulder most definitely not

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**option 1**

```
<?php
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vup_file";
if ($STH = $DBH->query($sql)) {
    if ($STH->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "rows matched the query."; 
    }
    else {
        echo "No rows matched the query.";
    }
}
```

---

**option 2**
@phil is right if you are going to count the rows in the query , you might as well read the value:

```
<?php
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as rowCount FROM vup_file";
$STH = $DBH->query($sql)
$row = $STH->fetch();
if ($row['rowCount'] > 0) {
    echo "rows matched the query."; 
}
else {
    echo "No rows matched the query.";
}
```

Should work, as long as connection and query are valid

Comment: If they're just checking for *count > 0* then the query might as well be `SELECT 1 FROM vup_file`

Comment: @Phil you mean `LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: I want to store the Maximum Id value in a php variable using pdo

Comment: @SrinathNaidu use max() function

Comment: @meda what is the difference between `fetchColumn()` and `rowCount`?

Comment: @meda no, I don't. Why bother making the database `COUNT` if you're not going to use the result

Comment: @SrinathNaidu I added more options for you

Comment: Your third option will **always** return a *truthy* value meaning that you will **always** see *"rows matched the query."*

Comment: @Phil what is a truthy value

Comment: @meda any value that can be implicitly converted to boolean `true`. See http://php.net/manual/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: @Phil Im sure `fetch()` return false when there isnt any row to fetch

Comment: @meda it does indeed however, a simple, un-grouped `SELECT COUNT(*)` query will **always** return a single row.

Comment: @Phil he didnt use group by, but I removed that option. I trust you that you know what you are talking about ;)

Comment: @meda sorry, my `GROUP BY` comment (which I've edited now) was just meant to point out that when you group the results, you'll get more rows.

Comment: oh ok but it is interesting, how do I reproduce this, I would love to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135425/error-in-storing-the-result-from-mysql-in-a-php-variable-pdo/26135545?noredirect=1#comment40965185_26135545)

> I want to store the Maximum Id value in a php variable using pdo

it seems you want something like this...

```
$max = $DBH->query('SELECT MAX(Id) FROM vup_file')->fetchColumn();
if ($max === false) {
    echo 'There are no records in this table';
}
```

I'm not sure why you bothered with the `COUNT(*)` query.